# BigQuery Data Transfer error for scheduled queries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

Im keep getting this error when I try to go to the scheduled queries dashboard.
I have a scheduled query that is importing aggregated data from another project trough a service account.
The import seems like it's working for a while but then shortly after I get this error.

```
Error loading location europe: BigQuery Data Transfer service account does not have sufficient permission. Please ask the project owner to disable the BigQuery Data Transfer service and then re-enable it.

Error loading location asia-northeast3: Unknown Error
```

It looks like I get this error multiple times for multiple regions.To make it work (for a while) I disabled the relevant API and reactivated it but after a while I keep getting the same errors.

I'm not if this could be a permission error (if the service account trough which this data transfer is being made does not have sufficient permission) or it's an API problem.
Do you guys know what could be the issue here and how I could test this out?

Comment: The Unknown Error loading location asia-northeast3 (and a few others) is a known issue that the BigQuery team is currently working in a fix for. That error should not influence your scheduled queries performance. I have the same error appear and my scheduled queries run fine.

Comment: Are these error messages affecting your scheduled queries?

Regarding the error message related to the permissions, by disabling and re-enabling the API it should be fixed; however, it seems that it's not working for you. Given that you are using a custom service account, could you indicate the permissions you granted to it?

The "Unknown Error" is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/158495351) as was mentioned in the previous comment.